# Blank UIImage when I combined many large images in one UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I would like to combine vertically many images in one image.
My images have the same size 1500x2122.

My problem is, depending on the number of images to combine, the final image is blank.
With 7 images, the final image is ok.
With 8, the final image is blank.

```
extension UIImage {

    class func combineTopToBottom(image1: UIImage, withImage image2: UIImage) -> UIImage {

        let size:CGSize  = CGSize(width: image1.size.width, height: image1.size.height + image2.size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

        image1.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: image1.size.height))
        image2.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: image1.size.height, width: size.width, height: image2.size.height))

        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return finalImage!
    }
}
```

In my controller, the function below is added to `ViewDidLoad` in order to add the final `UIImage` in the view:

```
func addImageStrip_v2() {

        var newCombinedImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: self.imagesStrip[1].image)

        for i in 1..<self.imagesStrip.count{
            newCombinedImage = UIImage.combineTopToBottom(image1: newCombinedImage!, withImage: UIImage(data: imagesStrip[i].image)!)
        }

        self.imageView.image = newCombinedImage
        self.imageView.addRatioConstraint()

    }

func addRatioConstraint() {
        let aspectRatioImageView:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .width, multiplier: self.image!.size.height/self.image!.size.width, constant: 1)
        self.addConstraint(aspectRatioImageView)
}
```

I have no error in the console when the final image is blank.

I'm sure it's a size problem. I tried to add "smaller" images (1500x1190), and the limit number of images that I can combined, is higher than if I used my large images.

Is `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` limited in size?

EDIT 1

[Memory gauge](https://streamable.com/8tie9) screencast. "Peaks" are when `addImageStrip_v2` is called.

Thanks

Comment: What happens to the memory gauge as the code runs?

Comment: @matt I added a screencast of the gauges when app is running.

Comment: Could be a leak. What does Instruments say, on a device? Have you tried `for i in 1..<self.imagesStrip.count{ autoreleasepool {` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a memory issue. The code below solved it:

```
for i in 1..<self.imagesStrip.count{ autoreleasepool {
```